# How to convert this method to work with Long instead of Int

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Suppose I have the following method:

**My question is:** What changes can I make to the method below would allow me to implement this same function except while reading type `Long` (from an `inputstream` or should I use a `DataInputStream` instead)? (The call `is.readLong();` will be used somewhere in the method probably) Essentially I want a timeout on `input.readLong()`.

```
public static int readInputStreamWithTimeout(InputStream is, byte[] b, int timeoutMillis) throws IOException
{
     int bufferOffset = 0;
     long maxTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeoutMillis;
     while (System.currentTimeMillis() < maxTimeMillis && bufferOffset < b.length) 
     {
         int readLength = java.lang.Math.min(is.available(),b.length-bufferOffset);
         // can alternatively use bufferedReader, guarded by isReady():
         int readResult = is.read(b, bufferOffset, readLength);
         if (readResult == -1) break;
         bufferOffset += readResult;
     }
     return bufferOffset;
 }
```

**Method summary:** This method is designed to read from an `Inputstream` called `is` until a certain amount of time has passed (then it stops reading, exits the method and returns `bufferOffset`.) Essentially there is a `timeout` in the form of `int timeoutMillis` that will put a limit on reading the `inputstream`.

**Method calling:**

```
     byte[] inputData = new byte[1024];
    int readCount = readInputStreamWithTimeout(System.in, inputData, 6000);  // 6 second timeout
```

**Notice:** The line that says `int readResult = is.read(b, bufferOffset, readLength);` is using `read()` function which doesn't accept the type `Long`.

Essentially this would be how it might be executed:

```
Long inputData = 0;
inputData = readInputStreamWithTimeout(System.in, inputData, 6000);  // 6 second timeout
```

And something like this?

```
public static Long readInputStreamWithTimeout(InputStream is, byte[] b, int timeoutMillis) throws IOException
{
         Long something = 0;
         int bufferOffset = 0;
         long maxTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeoutMillis;
         while (System.currentTimeMillis() < maxTimeMillis && bufferOffset < b.length) 
         {
             int readLength = java.lang.Math.min(is.available(),b.length-bufferOffset);
             something = is.readLong();
             if (readResult == -1) break;
             bufferOffset += readResult;
         }
         return something;
}
```

Comment: It takes me a time read properly and understand what you need. Why do you need read in a single time an amount of bytes higher than maximum int? If you do not need that, you can just change `int bufferOffSet` for `long bufferOffser`.

Comment: Please try to minimize the content of the question. Please follow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JTejedor Because the method that I am trying to recieve is using output.writeLong();

Comment: @v.coder This question is literally  14 lines of code in one method. How can you say that it is not minimal?

Comment: Because the question comes after approximately 7 lines of text and 14 lines code. Usually it is good to put the question at the beginning so that it gets user's attention.

Comment: Input stream reads byte by byte, why would you want to read it as a long, its just a bit of wasted space.

Comment: @v.coder ok refresh now its fixed?

Comment: @luckydog32 Oh true. I am actually using a `DataOutputStream` to write the `Long` so I guess I should change this method to use `DataInputStream is` instead of a regular `InputStream` right?

Comment: @elis Yeah that would work, you can just use the readLong() method from the DataInputStream then.

Comment: Can you use a `Scanner` instead?

Comment: Any chance of switching to nio? Reading with blocking IO with a timeout is next to impossible.

Comment: @Bohemian Scanner is a lot slower than an Input Stream for large documents.

Comment: I see two problems here, one is trying to mimic `NIO` (poorly) with blocking IO, and the other is using `DataOutputStream` on the sending side, without using `DataInputStream` on the receiving side. If you want a timeout, set a read timeout on the socket, and wait for the exception.

Comment: @Kayaman Hmm okay so it would be something like `socket.setSoTimeout(1000)` right before the  input.readLong() is called?

Comment: @teppic I don't know how to do that but if it is able to readLong() with a timeout then I guess go for it?

Comment: @Kayaman if it is easier to use DataInputStream then I would like to switch to that instead, so I guess i would just change the method parameters and then readLong() and then return a long and it should be fine?

Comment: What are you planning to do if the call times out? The stream may be in an unknown state if you've only read part of your long. Is closing the stream acceptable in this case?

Comment: Yes, they're meant to be used together. You don't want to re-invent the wheel and parse the output of a `DataStream` yourself. @teppic You can't read a part of a long, as `readLong()` will buffer until it gets 8 bytes from the wire, so either you get it or you don't get it. Of course there's still the actual problem of a timeout. That's not a standard way to do things with blocking IO, so you most likely have a design problem you're trying to fix with this. **If** you need a read timeout, use `soTimeout`, but a timeout is almost surely the wrong thing to do here.